# How is NTFS licensed?

Tags: intellectual-property, licensing

What are the restrictions on NTFS and in what ways can I use NTFS?

Can I boot from NTFS without worrying about Microsoft suing me?

Is it based on if I have a Windows license?  I asked a similar question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/990568/how-is-ntfs-licensed) and [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300618/how-is-ntfs-licensed).

Comment: You can't "boot" NTFS, because that's literally not the sort of thing you can do with a filesystem. What are you actually asking if you can do?

Comment: @cpast It has a boot sector(although I'm not really sure if this is required) so yes it can be booted. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Partition_Boot_Sector You might be right though that it's not important in distinguishing booting a NTFS drive and using a formatted NTFS drive on the computer.

Comment: "Booting" is something associated with programs. You can boot *from* NTFS, but cannot *boot* NTFS.

Comment: @cpast when using the Ntfs boot sector.... is that the right terminology then?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike with its ExFAT filesystem and VFAT filesystem extensions, Microsoft has chosen not to issue any patents regarding NTFS, so there's no need to obtain a licence from Microsoft to use it.  The particular "invention" of a boot sector is much older than NTFS, and even Microsoft itself, and so wouldn't have been patentable by them in any case.

Comment: Just because it isn't patented, doesn't mean it's open licensed.

Comment: @RonBeyer I didn't say it was open licensed, I said a licence wasn't required. Patents provide the only means available to Microsoft to prevent its use without a licence. A trademark would only prevent someone using the name in certain contexts, copyright would only prevent someone from copying Microsoft's own code.

Comment: But a patent doesn't protect an invention against use.

Comment: @phoog The ExFAT and VFAT patents prevented companies from producing products that used ExFAT and the VFAT extensions without a licence.  Microsoft even sued one company, TomTom, for failing to obtain a licence.

Comment: @phoog Also patents quite clearly protect an invention against unauthorized use.  For example, 35 USC 271 (a) says "Except as otherwise provided in this title, whoever without authority makes, **uses**, offers to sell, or sells any patented invention, within the United States or imports into the United States any patented invention during the term of the patent therefor, infringes the patent."

Comment: "prevented companies from producing products": Of course.  A patent prohibits unlicensed manufacture of protected inventions.  But while you need a license to *produce* something containing a patent-protected invention, you do not need a license to *use* such a product.  As to 35 USC 272(a), does that mean that someone who finds a patent-protected cigarette lighter (or any other device) on the street can't use it without first obtaining a license?  I don't think so.

Comment: @phoog  You do in fact need a licence to use an patented invention, as I showed above. That's normally an implied one obtained by purchasing a legitimately produced product, but such an implied licence wouldn't have existed if you used someone else's open source ExFAT file system code.

Comment: If you can explain how that licensing works in the case of a patent-protected device found on the street or given by the purchaser to another person, I will reverse my downvote.  In other words, quoting the use of the word "use" in the statute doesn't show that it applies in either case.  It would be necessary to consider judicial interpretation, for example of whether "use" is limited in some way, perhaps to use in manufacture as opposed to use by an end user. It would also be necessary to look at the exceptions "otherwise provided" for in title 35.

Comment: @phoog That wouldn't be relevant to the question as that isn't what the original poster asked about. I gave you an authoritative source clearly showing that use requires authorization. If you don't want to believe that I'm not going to waste my time further.

Comment: A statutory citation beginning with "except as otherwise provided" may be authoritative, but it is the opposite of conclusive.  For example, US immigration law says "it shall be unlawful for any alien to depart from or enter or attempt to depart from or enter the United States except under such reasonable rules, regulations, and orders, and subject to such limitations and exceptions as the President may prescribe," yet anyone citing that in support of the proposition that aliens may not leave or enter the US would be sorely mistaken at best. You have to look at the actual exceptions.